# How to create a UserAssertion for "AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf()" when using Owin session cookie authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, cookies, oauth, owin

I am working on a pair of simple .NET applications where users can subscribe to distribution lists for automated reports. I need the front end app to be able to authenticate on behalf of the user when making requests to the backend app that manages the distributions.

I have the app permission etc. all set up correctly in Azure, but the AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf() call requires a UserAssertion object. All of the examples I have seen pass a JWT token that they easily pull from the BootstrapContext or wherever their Tokens live into the UserAssertion constructor, something like this:

```
var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(bootstrapContext?.Token);
```

or like this:

```
 var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(bootstrapContext?.Token, 
                                       "urn: ietf:params:oauth: grant - type:jwt - bearer",
                                        userName);
```

The issue is I am not using Token Authentication; I'm using session authentication via Owin.

My question is if it is possible to use info stored somewhere in the OwinContext perhaps in `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User` to create or fake a token or otherwise manually assemble a UserAssertion? Or is it just not possible to do OAuth with session cookie authentication?